# onChange with Input dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

got some trouble with my Code. I try on the fly depending from user input to change my background color. But i cant get it. I think it's totaly easy and i'm just blind.

Here are my HTML Mark up & jQuery:

```js
        <script>
        
            var height;
            var width;

            $('#height-button').click(function() {
              height = $("#height").val();
              $("#square").css("height", height);
            });
            
            $('#width-button').click(function() {
              width = $("#width").val();
              $("#square").css("width", width);
            });

           $(function () {
                $("#cpl").change(function(){
                    $("#square").css("background", $("#cpl").val());
                });
            })
            
            $(function () {
                $('#cp1').colorpicker();
            });
            
        </script>
```

```html
<head>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="ASSETS/BT-CP/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ASSETS/CSS/costum.css">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="ASSETS/BT-CP/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid py-4 col-12">
            <div id="square"></div>
        </div>
            
        <div class="container py-4 controller-interface">
        
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link rounded-0 active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link rounded-0" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link rounded-0" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            
            <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 bg-light border border-top-0" id="pills-tabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane show active rounded-bottom" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
                
                <div class="row">
                    
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="input-group py-2">
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Breite" id="width">
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn" id="width-button" type="button">Breitenangabe bestätigen</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="input-group py-2">
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Höhe" id="height">
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn" id="height-button" type="button">Höhenangabe bestätigen</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="input-group py-2">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Farbe" id="cp1" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane rounded-bottom" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
              <div class="tab-pane rounded-bottom" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

do i have to do something that it will be changed on the fly? It would be nice if it would change instantly if the user trigger an input with the color-picker.

Thank ya for your time!

Comment: Try using the debugging tools provided with your browser and let us know if the console is throwing any errors

Comment: would you be able to post a working snippet?? it'd help

Comment: Is it the `change` function on `#cpl` that is not working? I can't find any element with the id of `cpl`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen cp1 is present as the ID of the input box. Take a look

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the cpl id is implement here: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Farbe" id="cp1" value="">

It's a plugin for a bootstrap color picker.

Comment: @JVLobo i will upload it to a webspace of mine. Gimme a second.

Comment: @Aderion then you have to update your snippet so it work, how do you expect us to be able to debug and help you if your code does not work ?

Comment: http://manager.jimador.de/ here can you find a working version

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you are having is because your ID for the colorpicker is `cp1` and in your js code you are using `cpl` (l - as a letter and not a number)

Change your code from:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#cpl").change(function(){
         $("#square").css("background", $("#cpl").val());
     });
 });
```

To this:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#cp1").change(function(){
         $("#square").css("background", $("#cp1").val()); // You can also use $(this).val() here to set the value
     });
 });
```

You can see a working demo of your code here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KerMKg
I wasn't able to init the color picker but you can enter the value like `#000` into the box and it will change the background

Comment: We do not post answers for typo's, as they are not code issues, they are spelling issues. SO even has a built-in "Vote/Flag to close" method for exactly that purpose.

Comment: As the OP says in the comment, CPL is a generated id of the color picker

Comment: changed background in your code to background-color in HTML and CSS it work like a charm! Thank you sir!